# Is there a paper/article on contextual $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, multi-armed-bandits

I am reading the paper [A Contextual-Bandit Approach to Personalized News Article Recommendation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0146), where it refers to $\epsilon$-greedy (disjoint) algorithm. I suspect, that it is just a version of a K-armed bandit with regressors that estimate the average reward for an arm. However, I cannot find the description of this algorithm in the literature (papers, books, or other resources)